# Laravel select records with pivot table

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a little problem with eloquent. I have 3 tables. `Users`, `phrases`, and `phrase_user`.
phrase user contains columns: `id, phrase_id, user_id`
I need to select phrases with pivot table for example.
**This action with SQL will be like this...**

```
SELECT phrase FROM phrases 
LEFT JOIN phrase_user ON  phrases.id = phrase_user.phrase_id
LEFT JOIN users ON phrase_user.user_id = $userId
```

This is my index function in controller

```
$phrases = DB::table('phrases')->orderBy('id','desc')->Paginate(5);
$user = Auth::user(); 
       
return view('pages.phrases.index')->with(['phrases' => $phrases, 'user' => $user]);
```

I also have written these functions in models...
Phrase model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

User model:

```
public function phrases()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Phrase')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In this case, paginator is not working properly because `$phrases = DB::table('phrases')->orderBy('id','desc')->Paginate(5);`  There is some problem..

In conclusion: I need to show only my phrases in phrases page. every user must have their phrases.

Comment: I suppose you could do `$user->phrases()->>orderBy('id','desc')->paginate()` Have you tried to do it this way before?

Comment: In this case how can i call pagination? instead of  {{ $phrases->links() }} this?

Comment: @lukatatrishvili you don't need to call `links()`. If you want the items in the pagination without all the paginations extra property then you should be able to send this to your view `$phrases >items()`; this would be the array of the items only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you really help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$userId = 2;

$phrases = DB::table('phrases')->whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
    $q->whereId($userId);
})->orderBy('id','desc')->Paginate(5);

$user = Auth::user();

return view('pages.phrases.index')->with(['phrases' => $phrases, 'user' => $user]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using lowercase paginate

```
$phrases = DB::table('phrases')->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(5);
```